# Module not found: Error: Package path ./v4 is not exported from package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I was building a react project but when I tried to run it. It showed the following error:

> ```
> Module not found: Error: Package path ./v4 is not exported from package
> ....\node_modules\uuid (see exports field in ....\node_modules\uuid\package.json)
> ```

I imported using the following code:

```js
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like an import issue in uuid. Try updating the import statement as:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```